# How to match SQL results with AD results and the other way around

Tags: sql, powershell, active-directory, inventory-management

I have to write a script that will query AD for users from a specific department that I will prompt user to input initially and then to output the software that is installed on the all machines that a specific user from the chosen department. I want to be able to see all the software from all the machine(s) that specific is logging on.

Presently I am using the following parts:

1) A query in AD to get the users from a specific department:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Dept = Read-Host "Enter the desired department"
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(Department=*$Dept*))"
$colResults = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $strFilter |
          Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName
```

2) I am also using a script from the person before me, that performs a query in SQL combined with LanDesk. See below:

```
$SQLServerLANDESK = "usernam\password"  
$SqlConnectionLANDESK = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$global:dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable

$LONA = ""
$o = 0

function doit() {
    $SqlConnectionLANDESK.ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServerLANDESK; Database=   $SQLDBNameLANDESK;uid=useraidi; pwd=parola"
    $SqlConnectionLANDESK.Open()

    $QueryLANDesk = @"

SELECT DISTINCT A0.DISPLAYNAME, A0.LOGINNAME,A0.PRIMARYOWNER,A0.TYPE, A1.OSTYPE, A2.SUITENAME, A2.PUBLISHER, A2.VERSION  
FROM Computer A0 (nolock) LEFT OUTER JOIN Operating_System A1 (nolock) ON A0.Computer_Idn = A1.Computer_Idn LEFT OUTER JOIN AppSoftwareSuites A2 (nolock) ON A0.Computer_Idn = A2.Computer_Idn  
WHERE  A0.DEVICENAME like '%D02DI0907061%'
 or A0.DEVICENAME like '%D02DI0929860%'

"@

    $CommandLANDesk = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($QueryLANDesk, $SqlConnectionLANDESK) 
    $CommandLANDesk.fill($dt) | out-null

    $dtrc = $dt.Rows.Count
     Write-Host "($i) Searching all cores ($dtrc machines)..."

    $SqlConnectionLANDESK.Close() 
}

 foreach ($i in  1..10)
 {if ($i -eq 6) {continue}
  $SQLDBNameLANDESK = "database"
  $SQLServerLANDESK = "username\parola"
  doit
 }

Write-Host 

$dt.select("displayname like '%$LONA%'") | export-csv H:\TEST\add-remove_TEST_LOGINNAME.csv # | foreach  {  $o++  }

# "$o machines found."
```

I want to be able to basically connect the result search from point 1 and match it with the "PRIMARYOWNER" which is in DistinguishedName format and to store those in a table back in SQL.  How do I do that?